# Accessing Singleton in iOS App

Tags: ios, singleton, reachability

This is quite a simple question about Singletons that I'm hoping someone can clear up for me quickly.

I'm following this tutorial for creating a Singleton for monitoring the network status in my app.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299

In my AppDelegate.m, I instantiate the manager as follows:

```
[ReachabilityManager sharedManager];
```

If I now want to check on this sharedManager, how do I access it from the viewControllers in my app?

This is what the class looks like:

```
#import "ReachabilityManager.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation ReachabilityManager

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Default Manager
+ (ReachabilityManager *)sharedManager {
    static ReachabilityManager *_sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedManager;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management
- (void)dealloc {
    // Stop Notifier
    if (_reachability) {
        [_reachability stopNotifier];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods
+ (BOOL)isReachable {
    return [[[ReachabilityManager sharedManager] reachability] isReachable];
}

+ (BOOL)isUnreachable {
    return ![[[ReachabilityManager sharedManager] reachability] isReachable];
}

+ (BOOL)isReachableViaWWAN {
    return [[[ReachabilityManager sharedManager] reachability] isReachableViaWWAN];
}

+ (BOOL)isReachableViaWiFi {
    return [[[ReachabilityManager sharedManager] reachability] isReachableViaWiFi];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private Initialization
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Initialize Reachability
        self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

        // Start Monitoring
        [self.reachability startNotifier];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easily:

```
#import "ReachabilityManager.h"

// Maybe in viewDidLoad
ReachabilityManager *sharedManager = [ReachabilityManager sharedManager];
// do stuff with your sharedManager
```

Comment: thanks for your help!  I noticed that in the tutorial, they created the sharedManager in AppDelegate.m: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299  Does this mean I shouldn't recreate it in another view?

Comment: @scientiffic As long as it compiles and runs, you can do whatever you want. The point of a singleton is not that you can only access it in a single place, but that there is only one singleton, and there is (usually) only one instance of the class. For more on the ideas behind singletons, check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I think I understand...but if I try, for example, using sharedManager.isReachable, I get an error "Property isReachable not found on object of type ReachabilityManager", which doesn't make sense to me since that method is defined in the class.

Comment: @scientiffic `isReachable` is a static method (it has the plus sign in it). You don't have to initialize a `Reachabilitymanager` object to use it. You just say `ReachabilityManager isRechable`. I can't answer any more of your question.s I've answered the question you posted.